# How to give credit for conference presentations on CV?

Tags: conference, research-undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate writing my CV.

I've given two presentations at undergraduate conferences on my (unpublished) research projects. I independently prepared my presentations but my lab mates/supervisor helped with the research. I want to list these presentations on my CV.

So my question is:

**How do I properly credit the contributions of others for these conference presentations?**

Should I just state the title of the talk and the conference name? Should I include the names of all the people that helped with the research? Since we didn't publish any papers, how do I determine what order the names should go in? Would it okay to list them alphabetically?

Note: these aren't peer-reviewed conference papers or anything. Any undergraduate student can submit an abstract and give a talk.

Answer (score 3):

All official and known conferences will need the authors to present their accepted work in oral or poster manner, and will publish the proceedings of the conference. I am not sure what you mean by `undergraduate conference`. But a presentation, where no paper has been presented to the research community, is not a big shot to be declared in CV, at least because there is no clear evidence for such accomplishment.

If there were any paper, You would mention the paper in a typical manner in your CV (considering yourself and any other one, who had any contribution) and insert an **unpublished** assertion in front of it. But in this situation, the better idea could be citing the thing in your CV, as a `Given Presentation at blah blah blah Conference`. If you do it, you might better explain something about `undergraduate conference`, because the reader may not be aware of this term, leading to confusion.

Good luck

Comment: Ask your faculty mentor - whether a 'paper'  is associated with a presentation is field specific (in my field (physics/materials physics presenations are just presentations') In my field - a presentation section is just a different section from a section on publications.  Listing in the presentation section, however, would be similar to what @Roboticist mentions.  author list, title, venue (conference )  (although without the worry about specifying  that is is 'unpublished' or not). A nice touch is a web address if the site with the agenda of the conference is still live.

Comment: If an abstract was submitted (at least that would be typical in many fields, even for an UG conference to give students experience) it would typically have had an author list. By the way - everyone on the author list is supposed ot have seen the abstract and have given approval of the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Conventions differ between fields. Mine is mathematics/TCS.

Conference contributions are listed on my CV (and on many others I've seen) in two places:

1. Extended abstracts in refereed proceedings are listed as a subsection under publications, complete with all coauthors.
2. Presentations given are listed as their own section, with a distinction between invited conference talks and other presentations. As a presentation is only given by a single presenter, there are no coauthors listed here.

Of course many contributions show up in only one part: If there are no refereed published proceedings, there is nothing listed there. If someone else gives the talk, I don't have a presentation to list.

Thus, in your case, I would not acknowledge the other's contributions on my CV at all (yet). Once there is at least a preprint, your coauthors will be listed there.